# Nokogiri with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri

Is there a way to use Nokogiri in Rspec?

Particularly I'm trying to take the response from a controller action and convert that into a Nokogiri object `page` and run Nokogiri-specific parsing like the one below:

```
page.search('input[name="some_name"]').size.should == 1
```

Where do I include Nokogiri - would that be in spec_helper.rb?

How do I convert the `ActionController::TestResponse` into a Nokogiri object?

Or is it possible to run the above kind of assertion by using plain Rspec syntax?

Comment: sounds like what capybara (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) (in particular, the querying module) is for.

Comment: not if you are testing for example a HTTP api which talks XML

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), as suggested by @sevenseacat, you can do something like:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
```

And then use the `Nokogiri` search methods.  But `capybara` is really a better way to go because it includes the query module that let's do do things like

```
expect(page).to have_css('input[name=some_name]', count:1)
```