# CSS selectors in rendered view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri

I would like to have access to CSS selectors in HTML rendered by RSpec. While testing my views, what I'm usually doing is something like this:

```
render partial: 'example_partial.html.erb'
rendered.should include("<option value=\"cool_option\" selected=\"selected\">")
```

to check if the correct option is selected in the input select. Is there a way to do it more Nokgiri-like? Some RSpec trick to handle checking if there is an element rendered?

```
  expect(rendered.css('input option:selected').value).to eg('cool_option')
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592436/nokogiri-with-rspec - you can use nokogiri methods on `Nokogiri::HTML(rendered)` assuming `rendered` is a html string.

Comment: or use capybara for testing https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara

Answer (score 0):

Use the Capybara gem and then you can use CSS selectors:

```
expect(rendered).to have_selector('select option', :text => "--- select ---")
```